# How can i manage the radio button selection in another button in Streamlit

Tags: python, radio-button, streamlit

I have one radio button that appears if I click the "Go" button. Then if I want to change the option in radio button, it will back to default, meaning the radio button will not appear since it is in event "Go" button. It goes back to default because, it just appears if that click event hit. so how can I maintain the question along with the radio button and I can change the option with what I want. can you help?

Below is my code:

```
def display_question(question_list, question_index):
    if question_index < len(question_list):
        question = question_list[question_index]["Question"]
        options = question_list[question_index]["Options"]
        st.write(question)
        # Display options as radio buttons
        selectedoption = st.radio("Options:", options, key=f"question{question_index}")
        st.session_state.selected_answers[question_index] = selected_option

if st.button("Let's go!"):
        question_index = 0  # Index to keep track of the current question
        st.session_state.question_index = question_index
        display_question(st.session_state.question_list, question_index)
```